# Media query for text spreading all over screen

Tags: css, media-queries, text-size

I would like the text to spread all over the webpage top to bottom, left to right.
I did it using vw, vh sizes for text size, placed inside a div.
within the text, there are links (.href) of which size is slightly larger.

It currently works with mac 13inch 2015 but for some reason doesn't with 13 inch of 2017.
It also doesn't work on ipad 11 inch portrait.

I am new to media queries and might be doing it all wrong.
Looking forward to your responses! Many thanks.

````
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    }


@media only screen 
and (min-width: 200px){
.div {
 width: 97vw;
 height: 97vh;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative;
 margin-bottom: 10vw;
}

.txt {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 text-justify: inter-word;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 2.5vh;
}

.href {
 color: #0000ff;
 font-size: 3vh;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.div {
 width: 97vw;
 height: 97vh;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative; /* text inside of div */
 margin-bottom: 10vw;
}

.txt {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 text-justify: inter-word;
 line-height: 1.5;
 font-size: 3vh;
}

.href {
 font-size: 3.5vh;
}

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
.div {
 width: 97vw;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 position: relative; /* text inside of div */
 margin-bottom: 10vw;
}

.txt {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 text-justify: inter-word;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin-bottom: 1rem;
 font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.href {
 font-size: 3vw;
}

}```
````

Comment: Please could you show us your relevant HTML and also describe what ‘ doesn’t work’ means?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - finally the problem was solved by making a media query for retina display.